# Oracle: function based index using dynamic values

Tags: performance, oracle, function, indexing, dynamic-data

I have one complex SQL queries. One of the simple part of the queries looks like:

```
Query 1:
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.number       = t2.number
   AND UPPER(t1.name)  = UPPER(t2.name)
   AND t1.prefix       = p_in_prefix;


Query 2:
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.number       = t2.number
   AND UPPER(t1.name)  = UPPER(p_in_prefix || t2.name)
   AND t1.prefix       = p_in_prefix;
```

I have function based index on table1 as (number, UPPER(name)). I have function based index on my table2 as (number, UPPER(NAME)). p_in_prefix is a input parameter (basically a number).

Because of these indexes my Query 1 runs efficiently. But Query 2 has a performance issue, as in Query 2, 't2.name' is prefixed with p_in_prefix.

I can not create function based index for Query 2 because p_in_prefix is a input parameter and I don't know while creating index, what values it might hold. How to resolve performace issue in this scenario? Any hint/idea would be appreciated. If you require more information, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Do the values in `p_in_prefix` correspond to any field in TABLE2?  It also appears the data in TABLE1.NAME is not set up properly - you have a separate PREFIX field, but that PREFIX appears to be pre-pended to some values of NAME.  You might try rewriting query 2 as `SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
 WHERE t1.number       = t2.number
   AND UPPER(t1.name)  = UPPER(t1.prefix || t2.name)
   AND t1.prefix       = p_in_prefix`.  Not sure how much that might buy you, but it's worth a shot.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND UPPER(t1.name)  = UPPER(p_in_prefix) || UPPER(t2.name)`.

As you have a function based index as `UPPER(NAME)` of `table2`, you should have an operand with the same expression in the query in order to make use of the function based index.

Using `UPPER(p_in_prefix || t2.name)` will not use the function based index as this does not match the function expression `UPPER(NAME)`. Note here that using `UPPER(t2.name)` does not cause any problems as `t2` is just a column alias.

Along with this, you can also pass an optimizer hint in your query in order to instruct the optimizer to use the index.

For more information read "Oracle Database 11g SQL" by Jason Price.

Also read Oracle Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_indexes.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm) and for optimizer hints [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm).

Comment: Dear Rachcha, I tried the way you suggested, but it did not help. Along with separating prefix from name, I added optimizer hint specifying the index names to be used. But still performance is very poor. Another thing is that, t2 table has the column perfix, but I do not wish to create another index on t2, because performance of inserts on that table are hampered.

Comment: One big problem of yours is that you are using the `p_in_prefix` parameter at runtime, hence you can't even create a separate index on that expression. Can you please put up your explain plan in the question so everyone can understand what is going on? :)